# Process.WaitForExit hangs while another installation is run

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, waitforexit

Good day!
I'm working on installer, which installs additional dependencies for my software using Process.Start.

```
foreach dependency:
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

The problem is when another msi installation is runned, WaitForExit hangs (and when I close this another msi installation, WaitForExit also exits).

I can't use timeouts, because dependencies are different with very different installation time.

Is there any ways to handle this situation and correctly kill process (actually I want to know is dependency is installing or just hanging)?
Many thanks.

**Solution:** in my case the problem is solved by checking if 'msiexec' process is running.

Comment: any reason you don't use the the installer projects from VS and include all relevant dependencies there ? or just embed them into youe EXE/DLL (assuming they are .NET you could even run them from memory) ?

Comment: Not all of them are .NET, dependencies can be downloaded from the internet. Installer is very big and complex.
Anyway, the question about hanging WaitForExit.

Comment: still - the installer projects from VS can install the dependencies... no need to write that yourself...

Comment: I don't need to rewrite the architecture of installer, but just to fix bug ;)

Comment: Why do you think it is "hanging" as opposed to just waiting for the exit of the process?  It sounds like it is doing exactly what you asked it to do, which is to `WaitForExit`

Comment: There are two processes:
1) My (dependency)
2) Some another msi installation (we know nothing about it)
When (2) is runned, (1) just waits for (2) exits. I want to show user some error message like "another installation is runned" instead of waiting.

Comment: I seem to remember that you can't run two MSI installers at the same time. Maybe this is a consequence of that?

Comment: Exactly. My installation runs only 1 msi at one time. But user can run some another. And this situation I want to handle.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with WaitForExit. It has to do with MSI. BTW, using a search engine would have led you to the answer of your question: http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg36036.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem - check global mutex, created by msiexec. This is also a correct way to check if another msi installation is running.

```
    public static bool WaitAnotherMsiInstallation(int timeout)
    {
        const string MsiMutexName = "Global\\_MSIExecute";

        try
        {
            using (var msiMutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(MsiMutexName, MutexRights.Synchronize))
            {
                return msiMutex.WaitOne(timeout);
            }
        } 
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
        {
            // The named mutex does not exist.
            return true;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // Mutex was disposed between opening it and attempting to wait on it
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is some details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372909(VS.85).aspx